# Searching in archived channels in Slack

Tags: slack

Is there a way in Slack to do a text search in all channels - including archived channels?

I have a lot of archived channels, so don't want to search them all individually and don't want to unarchive them.

Answer (score 0):

Search results from archived channels are included by default.